# Sustained Damage from A Speeding Vehicle

Tags: forces

I am a layman when it comes to Physics and equations, but I always believed that most police forces in the country viewed speed limit exceeding before prosecution on the basis of 10% + 2.  So if you were doing up to 35mph in a [30 area] being ((30 * 1.10)+2) they would not prosecute; similarly in a [70 area] it would be ((70 * 1.1)+2) being 79.
However, from a physics point of view I understand that speed is relative and not proportional.  Therefore the additional damage, should one be hit by a moving vehicle at 33mph over the damage sustained at 30mph,  Would be the same as the additional damage sustained from being hit at 73mph over and above being hit at 70mph, and NOT 77mph.
It may be clearer if I said a car was 100m long and it a brick wall.  At 30mph it crumples to 70m and at 33mph it would crumple to 67m long.  Then at 70mph it crumples to 30m long and at 73mph crumples to 27m long.  My question is whether my understanding is correct and that at 77mph [being a 10% increase in speed] if it was proportional it would not be 23m long.
Basically being hit at 33mph vice being hit at 73mph the additional damage from that 3mph would be the same.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to arise from several assumptions that I believe are making the situation appear so odd to you.

To start, I'll address the initial reasoning.

The equation for speed where they would ticket you in itself seems fairly arbitrary and doesn't exist in any law I know of.  Them pulling you over seems more situational.

Another reason why this ~10% rule seems to happen is that you can't expect people to drive exactly on the speed limit.  If they are pretty close, it could have been measurement error in finding their speed.  It's also generally close enough to the limit to be a non-issue not worth the hassle.

As far as the physical meat of your question, that is still not accurate.  For pure translational movement kinetic energy is given by $$E = \frac 12 mv^2$$ Where E is energy, m is mass and v is velocity.

Essentially energy is proportional to velocity squared.  The energy of a car moving 10% extra speed will obviously change for different velocities.  What might not be as obvious is that an extra set speed added on (3 mph in this example) will not have the same energy for different speeds.

$\frac 12 m (73)^2 - \frac 12 m (70)^2$ is not the same as $\frac 12 m (33)^2 - \frac 12 m (30)^2$.

Essentially the question is somewhat misguided.  To recap: The relationship you mentioned is just a rule of thumb and not an official rule.  The 10% is not meant to limit the energy above the speed limit to within a specific value.  Even if it were energy above the speed limit, it wouldn't be a constant difference, due to the $v^2$ relationship.

Comment: So basically my thinking is flawed.  The additional damage of the 3 extra mph will not be the same caused by being hit at 33mph to that of being hit at 73mph.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no detailed knowledge about collisions involving cars, but I believe that the kinetic energy (KE) of a vehicle is a better measure of the amount of damage it can do (How vague can I get?) when it hits a stationary 'obstacle'. Kinetic energy is proportional to the square of the speed. So…

Ratios of difference in KEs at 63 mph and 60 mph compared with difference in KEs at 33 mph and 30 mph is as ($63^2-60^2) \ \text{to}\ (33^2-30^2)$ which is approximately 2 to 1, so 3 mph makes twice as much difference to the KE at 60 mph as at 30 mph! This makes your point even more strongly. I can only assume that speed limit 'tolerances' are not based on considerations of damage. Maybe they should be!

In algebraic terms, $$\Delta E_k = \Delta \left(\frac{1}{2}mv^2 \right) \approx mv \Delta v.$$